# How can I override my current sharing rules on Facebook for just the current post?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook I have my post sharing rules set to "Friends; Except [Group]" by default. However, on occasion I want to post something to just "[Group]" or I want to include them (i.e. post to "Friends").

However, if I change the audience of the current post Facebook remembers this and assumes that it's what I want for all subsequent posts, so I have to remember to change it back before posting again.

Is there a way I can just change the audience for the current post only?

Comment: Ugh. I've been bit by that more than once. It is annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now there is no official way to change the audience for the current post only. You have to change it everytime, otherwise it will use last selected audience by default.

From [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/120939471321735):

> You'll find an audience selector tool most places you share status updates, photos and other things you post. **The tool remembers the audience you shared with the last time you posted something and uses the same audience when you share again unless you change it**.